# How to install a new assembly in my framework?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, .net-assembly

searching for a method step by step how to install in my toolbox SourceGrid 2.0 which is available on the net. 
I am using visual studio C# (2010)
 Thank you in advance.

Comment: You mean you want to install it in the GAC ? or you just want to install Source Grid on your machine ? Where did you get SourceGrid 2.0 ?

Comment: I got the file which contains the assemblies on this web site: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3531/SourceGrid-Open-Source-C-Grid-Control        But I have no idea how to include it to my project. I tried to add the assemblies manually but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user1523566 do you really want to use this library when their is not clear instruction on how to install it

Comment: Change the framework you are using!

Answer (score 0):

- Open the toolbox window in Visual Studio.
- Right click into the toolbox and select `Add Tab`
- Give the new group a meaningful name
- Right click into the group and select `Choose items...`
- Click on the bottom right button `Browse...`
- Select the assemblies that contains a UserControl or a Component
- Click on the open button of the FileOpenDialog
- Click on the OK button of the "Choose Toolbox items" dialog

Your new items show up in the toolbox.

Comment: What I want is to use it not to add it to my toolbox. Adding it to my toolbox does'nt solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

- goto http://sourcegrid.codeplex.com/releases/view/91226
- click on SourceGrid_4_40_bin
- download SourceGrid_4_40_bin.zip\SourceGrid_4_40_bin\SourceGrid\Release
- extract  it in the folder \SourceGrid_4_40_bin\SourceGrid\Release contains
- then follow this for instructions on how to add the reference
  http://larsjacob.wordpress.com/2010/06/15/use-a-dll-library-in-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: I'd already followed all theses steps before but it show me this: Could not resolve assembly "assembly". The assembly is not listed as part of the framework. I want to make this assembly a part of my framework to make its use possible.

Comment: Follow this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx make sure that the selected frame work does not say Client Profile but just the framework if it does then change it so Client Profile is not selected